# Error splitting the input into NAL units - ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg tool (version 4.2.7) to combine a video and an audio stream. The size of the video stream is ~54GB and 30 hours long, and I downloaded it from a website. I cross-checked the content-length header and the file size in my OS after it was downloaded to check for any missing data, but there was no data lose. I manually watched the video skipping at an interval of every 10 mins to check if the video freezes at any point, it did not.

Muxing happens for certain frames, and then a large list of errors show up. So, I checked the integrity of the video stream using the below command

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 -v error -i 'video.mp4' -f null - 2>error.log
```

The error.log file repeats the below sequences of lines over and over.

```
[NULL @ 0x55aebb55e080] Invalid NAL unit size (1835295092 > 200670).
[NULL @ 0x55aebb55e080] missing picture in access unit with size 200674
[h264 @ 0x55aebb6dcf80] Invalid NAL unit size (1835295092 > 200670).
[h264 @ 0x55aebb6dcf80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

I have uploaded the entire log here [error.log](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ofi4vwpge3ruybd/error.log/file)

I checked similarly for any errors in the audio stream, and there were no errors. I am really confused as to what is happening. Help me understand what's wrong with the video stream.